# How to isolate text in a <p> tag to bold without changing the format of remaining paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have three sections of text in there own `<p></p>` and I need to bold just a couple of words in each paragraph. So my question is how would I properly bold "CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc." using CSS without having the text that follows appear below the bold text. The reason I'm asking this is because whenever I try to isolate the text I want to bold in another div or p tag the remaining text appears below the bolded text.

Here is my html

```
<div id="content">
   <p class="copy"> CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc. have been proudly serving real estate investors nationwide since 1991.</p>

</div>
<!--End of content-->
```

Here is my current project on codepen if it helps http://codepen.io/Austin-Davis/pen/IpDLu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To bold some text in a paragraph you could use the `<b>`, `<strong>` tag or a `<span>` with styling set. These options would look like this:

```html
I want to <b>bold</b> a word.

This word is <strong>bolded</strong>.

The following word is <span style="font-weight: bold;">bolded</span>.
```

Note that your choice of tag has *semantic* implications. With the development of HTML5 there is a movement to make the tags that you're using carry meaning beyond just having them there for display purposes. [You can read a bit about a few of the relevant meanings here.](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/)

Though I used inline styling in my code snippet above to style that span, I would probably use a stylesheet to set the style on an actual webpage. It's good practice to separate your HTML markup and the styling.

Oh, and one last thing: the reason that placing your text in a p or div tag moves it to the next line is because those elements are, by default, set to `display: block;`. If you want to use one of those tags (which you shouldn't for semantic reasons), you could set them to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`. [Read all about the display property here.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: Thank you wasn't aware of the underlying issue regarding the default display of p and div. Now that I'm aware of span I should run into this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a STRONG tag but I prefer to keep it flexible by using a SPAN. You can set the style for the SPAN (or for that matter the STRONG) in CSS.

```
<style>
#content p.copy span {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<div id="content">
<p class="copy"> <span>CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc.</span> have been proudly serving real estate investors nationwide since 1991.</p>

</div>
<!--End of content-->
```

Comment: @jmeas has a fuller answer. I've left this answer as it shows your original code with changes made.

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer but I have to accept jmeas for answering first

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p class= "copy"> <b>CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc.</b> have been proudly serving real estate investors nationwide since 1991.</p>

.copy b 
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you want to do it in CSS?  The simplest way would be to put `<b> </b>` tags around the CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc.

```
<div id="content">
   <p class="copy"> <b>CLX Exchange Accommodators, Inc.</b> have been proudly serving real estate investors nationwide since 1991.</p>

</div>
<!--End of content-->
```

You could also use `<strong> </strong>` tags, however it might also italicize the text in some older browsers

Comment: The reason I want to do this in css is I firgue changing text color/weight is styling, which is best done in CSS. Also I need to do this in multiple places and if I need to revise them it would be easier to edit one line of css then all the lines of html

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that when you said CSS you only wanted to do it in CSS (for example if you didn't have access to the HTML source.) But if you want to specify just a subsection of text within a div or class, there is no way to do that in straight CSS without marking it in some way in the HTML. Like the above answers, you can then use CSS to define how you want to style the marked subsections.  Also, why the -1 for the basically the same answer as the one you chose?

Comment: I didn't give the minus 1 you need at least 125 rep for that. My guess is that you got a minus 1 with for providing answer with only HTML and no css.